# How to align div within another div vertically?

Tags: css

I want to show multiple DIVs elements (different height) inline within another DIV. And all these DIVs should be aligned vertically TOP. If you resize container DIV then inside DIVs will go new line and the second line position starts from the largest DIV in previous line (see picture):

[image]

This does not seem to work:

```
.containerDiv{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.insideDiv{
    text-align: center;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container div?

Comment: You should be sharing the `HTML` layout too, Just `CSS` wont help much :)

Comment: Thank you... flex-... do help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is perfect for this layout. Here's a simple example which should work as you intended. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gerrit0/ufyo34wb/).

I assume that the height of each box is determined by the content within the box. If you are setting the height manually for each box, then you can remove the flex-start, flex-grow, and flex-basis settings.

```css
.container {
  border: 4px solid #000;
  display: flex;

  /* otherwise everything goes on one row */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  
  /* Needed as otherwise it stretches to have evenly sized boxes on each row */
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  border: 4px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em;
  
  /* can't use width: 150px, but in this case it acts as if we did. */
  min-width: 150px;
  
  /* This is needed to prevent the boxes from dynamically resizing. */
  /* alternatively: flex: 0 1 0; */
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Words words words words words words words words words</div>
  <div class="item"> words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words</div>
  <div class="item"> words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words</div>
  <div class="item"> words words words words words words words</div>
  <div class="item">Words words words words words words words words words</div>
  <div class="item"> words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words words</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, on screen size greater then 768 px both set of div align with each other

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.upperDiv{
  width:20%;
  background-color:red;
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.upperContain{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
    margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.lowerContain{
   width:100%;
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.lowerDiv{
  width:20%;
  background-color:green;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
}
@media (min-width:768px){
  .upperContain{
  width:50%;
  display:block;
    float:left;
}
.lowerContain{
   width:50%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="upperContain">
  <div class="upperDiv" style="height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="upperDiv" style="height:30px;"></div>
  <div class="upperDiv" style="height:70px;"></div>
  <div class="upperDiv" style="height:40px;"></div>
  <div class="upperDiv" style="height:10px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="lowerContain">
  <div class="lowerDiv" style="height:50px;"></div>
  <div class="lowerDiv" style="height:40px;"></div>
  <div class="lowerDiv" style="height:20px;"></div>
  <div class="lowerDiv" style="height:40px;"></div>
  <div class="lowerDiv" style="height:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure the OP doesn't want to force 2 rows if the screen is big enough to fit everything on the first row.

Comment: yes, I corrected my answer after that. thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

CSS:

```
.main-container{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 250px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    padding:20px 0;
}
.secondary-div{
    border:solid 1px #000;
    width:50px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:50px;">Div1</div>
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:100px;">Div2</div>
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:120px;">Div3</div>
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:70px;">Div4</div>
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:100px;">Div5</div>
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:50px;">Div6</div>
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:120px;">Div7</div>
    <div class="secondary-div" style="height:70px;">Div8</div>
</div>
```